# Dry out some wet dirt in crawl space

Tags: leak, crawlspace, dehumidifier

We had a leak in a bathroom.  Some of the water got under the house.  Soaked up roughly 5 gallons of water from on top of the plastic sheeting as well as under it.  Now we have wet dirt, moist plastic sheeting and a little bit of moist insulation (not much of that).

Will it dry on its own or should I get a dehumidifier?  How long would I have to run the dehumidifier for?

Comment: The dehumidifier will tell you when it's done.  I mean it will cycle less often and fill the tank slower.  It won't really hurt the plastic sheeting to get wet for a week or two.  Get the water out of there before it molds, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the crawl space I would not get a humidifier for this it will dry on its own. I would put a fan in the area to circulate the air and decrease the drying time if you have a fan but I would not purchase anything special to dry out the crawl space it will dry on its own.